# Como retirar o último caractere de um campo no Firebird SQL

Tags: sql, firebird

Tenho um campo em uma tabela que só deveria conter 4 caracteres, 
percebi que o mesmo está com 5 caracteres e o último é o número zero.

Exemplo:

```
Código Errado: 45380
Código Correto = 4538
```

Tem como apagar o último caractere de um campo no Firebird SQL?

Comment: O que você já tentou fazer? esse campo é int ou string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode utilizar [CHARACTER_LENGTH](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-intfunc-char_length.html):

```
UPDATE minhaTabela
SET    minhaColuna = Substring(minhaColuna FROM 1 FOR 4)
WHERE  Character_length(minhaColuna) = 5
```

Desta forma apenas onde existir 5 caracteres será removido o ultimo.

Comment: A dica do Gabriel Rodrigues deu certo.
Obrigado!

Comment: @alexrdantas que bom que deu tudo certo, uso firebird há uns 2 anos já!

Answer (score 0):

Basta fazer um [`UPDATE`](http://www.firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-update.html) dividindo o valor por 10.

```
update minhaTabela
set Campo = Campo/10
where [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Você já tentou usar o método `strlen`?

```
   UPDATE suatabel SET campo = SUBSTR(campo , 1, strlen(campo)-1)
    where strlen(campo) = 5;
```

Comment: O que acontece com os valores que possuem 6 caracteres?

Comment: ele não mencionou isso na pergunta

Comment: Eu sei, mas estou tentando fazer um questionamento de modo a melhorar a sua resposta. Concorda que isso quebra o seu código?

Comment: Pronto resolvido.

Comment: Felipe, não me leve a mal, só estou tentando ajudar a melhorar. Concorda que nesse caso ela também só irá funcionar para os que possuem 5? O que acontece com os com 6 ou 7? Eu sei que ele não mencionou isso, mas e se por acaso eles existem? Não seria melhor continuar com `> 4` e no `SUBSTR` colocar o valor fixo para 4?

Comment: sim, ai basta por em um loop ou case, mas como eu vou saber o que ele tem na string? pode ser que tenha um numero 32330000000000000000000000,

Comment: Exatamente, ele pode ter esse valor, e para não precisar fazer um loop ou nada disso, apenas terá que utilizar `SUBSTR(campo, 1, 4)`. Faz sentido para você?

Comment: Depende, se ele quiser remover qualquer coisa do final, sim, mas e se não for um ZERO?